# Optimistic locking on redis in grails

Tags: grails, concurrency, transactions, redis

So what I want to achieve is school example of optimistic locking when 2 clients are incrementing the same number described in redis documentation ([***Optimistic locking using check-and-set*** part](http://redis.io/topics/transactions)) :

```
WATCH mykey
val = GET mykey
val = val + 1
MULTI
SET mykey $val
EXEC
```

So they are making optimistic locking using WATCH keyword which sounds pretty nice.

Also I am using Grails and looking at [Grails-redis plugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-redis). There is also another redis plugin which uses GORM but it doesn't work any more as I can see (last version is 1.0.0 and I couldn't install it in my application)

In plugin documentation there is some talk about redis transaction but I cannot figure how to write above example with optimistic locking.

I would be very grateful if someone know how to solve this.

EDIT : So grails-redis plugin support some kind of transactions but it actually wrap jedis (which is java library for redis) and I don't see that they are using WATCH keyword, just MULTI which don't suite me.
So I imported jedis (which does support WATCH) to my grails project and implemented this. It have passed without error but I haven't test it yet in 2 concurrent calls (hope that will work to :):

```
        Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
        // set some initial data
        jedis.set("num", 1 as String)

        // optimistic locking
        jedis.watch("num")
        def num = jedis.get("num") as Integer
        num = num + 1
        BinaryTransaction t = jedis.multi();
        t.set("num", num as String)
        t.exec()

        // print result
        def num2 = jedis.get("num")
        print num2
```

Thanks,
Ivan